# Removing an external IPython notebook magic extension

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I was wondering how external IPython magic extensions can be removed once installed.

E.g., let's say I used the deprecated `%load_ext` magic function to install a package

```
%install_ext path/to/the/some_package.py
```

I assume that this `package.py` extension will now be stored locally somewhere ... I did a search for "some_package.py" in the IPython dir but couldn't find anything. 
Anyways, do you have any tips for how to get rid of this "some_package.py" once installed?

Answer (score 1):

Okay found it. By default, the extensions are installed as .pyc files in `.ipython/extensions/`